# What is the url for a full github repo?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to clone my entire github repo onto a new machine. On the website, the url looks something like this:

https://github.com/MyName

However, when I do this:

```
git clone https://github.com/MyName C:/Users/MyName/Documents/GitHub/
```

I get

```
>Cloning into GitHub 'C:/Users/MyName/Documents/GitHub/'
>fatal: repository 'https://github.com/MyName' not found
```

Comment: That's the URL for an account, not a repo.

Comment: Go to the repo on github and look at the page. It is on there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`https://github.com/MyName` would be the URL for an account, not a repo. For instance, jQuery (the company) has an account at `https://github.com/jquery`. If I try to clone from that URL, I get a clone error:

```
git clone https://github.com/jquery
>>> Cloning into 'jquery'...
>>> fatal: repository 'https://github.com/jquery' not found
```

Which makes sense - that URL isn't of a repository.

Meanwhile, if I actually clone the project, `https://github.com/jquery/jquery`, it works:

```
git clone https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git
>>> Cloning into 'jquery'...
>>> remote: Counting objects: 36035, done.
>>> remote: Compressing objects: 100% (91/91), done.
>>> remote: Total 36035 (delta 60), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 35944
>>> Receiving objects: 100% (36035/36035), 21.72 MiB | 2.77 MiB/s, done.
>>> Resolving deltas: 100% (25434/25434), done.
>>> Checking connectivity... done.
```

If you want to clone all the repos under a username, there isn't a native way to do that. However, [clone-all](https://github.com/silky/clone-all) or [github-clone](https://github.com/Narnach/github-clone) seem to fit the bill as tools that'll do this for you.

The general procedure that you would need to do (by hand or with a tool) would be:

1. Get a list of URLS containing all repos for an org/user.
2. Clone each of theme using `git clone`.

Comment: thanks...that makes sense. But I actually do want to clone the account - everything? Is there not a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
git clone https://github.com/username/reponame.git
```

This is the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/MyName is only the URL for your account

Your account can have multiple repos, each one having its own URL:

- https://github.com/MyName/Repo1
- https://github.com/MyName/Repo2
- https://github.com/MyName/Repo3

To clone the specific repo, use something like

```
git clone https://github.com/MyName/Repo3.git C:/Users/MyName/Documents/GitHub/Repo3
```