# Trying to clone my entire GitHub account (windows)

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

Motherboard is blown on the old computer. Trying to set up the new computer (Windows)...and I cannot find out how to clone my entire account....and I need to.

The account url is this:

https://github.com/MyName

However, when I do this:

```
git clone https://github.com/MyName C:/Users/MyName/Documents/GitHub/
```

I get

```
>Cloning into GitHub 'C:/Users/MyName/Documents/GitHub/'
>fatal: repository 'https://github.com/MyName' not found
```

[I learned about repos vs accounts here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30016216/what-is-the-url-for-a-full-github-repo)

Comment: You need to clone repository by repository...

Comment: As far as I know, GitHub has no functionality that lets you do that. You'll probably have to do it manually for each repository.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [GitHub Repos API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-user-repositories) in order to list all your repos:

```
GET /users/:username/repos
```

From there you can loop and clone each one.

See for example this [bash script](https://gist.github.com/michfield/4525251) (from [Michael Field -- `michfield`](https://github.com/michfield)), which creates a shell `clone_allrepos_${usr}.sh` with the `git clone` command for each of your repos, taking into account [the pagination](https://developer.github.com/guides/traversing-with-pagination/):

```
usr="MyName";
url="https://api.github.com/users/${usr}/repos";
num=$(curl -sI "$url?page=1&per_page=100" | sed -nr 's/^Link:.*page=([0-9]+)&per_page=100>; rel="last".*/\1/p');
for ((i=1;i<=$num;i++)); do ( curl -s "$url?page=${i}&per_page=100" | grep "clone_url" | sed -nr 's/.*clone_url": "(.*)",/git clone \1/p' ); done >clone_allrepos_${usr}.sh
```

> Execute the created `.sh` when you are ready

```
 ./clone_allrepos_${usr}.sh
```